# running command in background and print output to a file without printing to screen

Tags: io-redirection, background-process

Suppose I want to run something in the background and print it to a file. However, when i do the following, it still prints to the screen... Does anyone know why? and what should i do? Thank you.

```
./mc.x & 2>&1 > test.out  
wait
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the background towards the end, like as:

```
./mc.x 2>&1 > test.out &
```

N.B.: Your redirections are ineffective as 2>&1 will make stderr go where stdout goes (i.e., display and which it anyway goes). Then, stdout will go
into a file test.out. Swapping their order would have made all stderr+stdout
go to the file test.out.

Comment: Doesn't your answer have the same problem with redirects? Should it not be `> test.out 2>&1`?

Answer (score 4):

Well, first the syntax you're trying to use should look like this:

`./mc.x > test.out 2>&1`

Notice extra `&` in command you have tried to use. And yes, this way you won't be able to send the program to a background.

TL;DR use `nohup` to accomplish what you want:

`nohup 2>&1 ./mx.c &`

This way program would not hang your terminal and send both `stdout` and `stderr` to a file named `nohup.out`.